# How to specify multiple inputs to ffmpeg amix filter

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am working on mixing more  audios with ffmpeg amix filter.I am able to achieve this using command line ,but I want to achieve the same with ffmpeg APIs.I have gone through the examples filtering_audio but it only takes one input . Can anyone tell me how to use multiple inputs for a filter? My purpose is to replace main audio with some other audio whenever there is data on second input.If there is no data on second input ,the filter should go on with one input.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `avfilter_graph_alloc()` to allocate avfilter graph as usual.
2. Create filter graph by `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr()` or `avfilter_graph_parse2()`. The former one will need you to create        `AVFilterInOut` linked list manually. Check their docs [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavfi.html#ga34f4ff420bd58da6747a3ff1fbedd001).
3. I'll assume you know how to decode the audio inputs to frames here. So the last thing is add them to their own `buffersrc`. Same as one input filter process, but call `av_buffersrc_add_frame()` multiple times in order.

There's an [example](http://www.voidcn.com/blog/dancing_night/article/p-6292960.html) written in Chinese. The code is not hard to understand, though some of them need a little fix for compatibility.

Comment: Thank you,exactly what I am looking for.